# Spring Transactional rollbackFor not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, transactional

I have a method to add a item to table and to test exception
My item is stored into table. Exception is raised, but Transaction was not 
rollback
My method

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, 
        rollbackFor={java.lang.Exception.class, java.lang.RuntimeException.class})
public MyBean addItem(MyBean bean, Integer iduser) throws Exception  {

    NalogBean nb = txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<MyBean>() {

        @Override
        public MyBean doInTransaction(TransactionStatus txStatus) {
            MyBean nbl = null;
            try {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(bean);
                throw new RuntimeException("Exception throwed!");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                txStatus.setRollbackOnly();
            }
            return nbl;
        }
    });

    return nb;          
}
```

My servlet-context is standard

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="rs.co"></beans:property>


    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>rs.co.mfp.klijent.finansije.model.NalogModel</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>

</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</beans:bean>
```

and when I call addItem it store bean into table.
Also I try without txTemplate, just 
          sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(bean);
          throw new RuntimeException("Exception throwed!");
but the same result. Item was stored into table.
Any idea?

Comment: You can remove RuntimeException in the rollbackFor block, because it inherits Exception. Additionally your repeating the default value for readOnly and propagation.

Comment: mh-dev, Yes, it is dobled, but I try everything. Also I try @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, 
   rollbackFor={java.lang.Exception.class, java.lang.RuntimeException.class})
 public NalogBean addNalog(NalogBean bean, Integer iduser) throws Exception {
  
  NalogModel model = null;
   model = convertToModel(bean);
   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(model);
  bean.setIdnalog(model.getIdnalog());
  if (true)
   throw new RuntimeException("Exception throwed!");
  //testRequired();
  return bean;
 
}, but it wrote data into table

Comment: To be honest, that what you are doing is to far away from the way I use spring nowadays. This whole xml configuration does Spring Boot automatically. (beside datasource config in a properties file).
One important question: Do you call this method from inside the same class? If yes than the annotation does not have any effect without aop.

Comment: No, I call this from springMvc project,  controllor. Here are link from test project http://www.mfp.co.rs/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/testHibernate.zip

Comment: I took a quick look into the code, but to be honest start again from scratch with state of the art spring mechanics. This code may have so many issues in it, because your doing to much at once without knowing what your doing. Go step by step and add every step only a little new piece. I highly encourage you to use spring-boot-starter-web.

Comment: I clean project from all unnecessary methods and class and update it into link.
You can see that I call /saveNalog where I call formBean = nalogService.addNalog(formBean, 1);
and pass throw service using propagation REQUIRED to keep session,

Comment: You are using MySQL then make sure you are using transaction capable tables (InnoDB type and not MyISAM type).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I convert table ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB
and everything is excelent
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you use Transaction annotation in above of method,dont need to using txStatus.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, 
        rollbackFor={java.lang.Exception.class, java.lang.RuntimeException.class})
public MyBeanId addItem(MyBean bean, Integer iduser) throws Exception  {

               return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(bean);

}
```

when be raised exception ,rollback transaction automatically 
i hope to help you

Comment: I try it, and I put if (true)
   throw new RuntimeException("Exception throwed!"); but bean is stored into table.

Comment: Here are link from test project http://www.mfp.co.rs/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/testHibernate.zip

Comment: Thanks to M. Deinum, he resolve my problem.
Problem was in MySQL table. 
I must convert table into InnoDB 
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB
and everything is excelent.